How to access a JSON object with XPath?
In a page, there is an inline  element, containing multiple objects.
I can access the full script, using an XPath like //script[contains(text(),'results')].
It contains multiple objects, among others, this one
{
"results": [
      {"entry":[...]},
      {"entry":[...]}
   ]
}

How can I access only results with XPath?

do you mean if the results has more than one result, you want the entire results property be returned? otherwise you can access results by simply $.results. and you can check if it has multiple items in it by $.results.length()

Xpath is for XML/HTML so a JSON object it's just a text() node for XPath.

Your question needs more clarity. Are you writing JavaScript, running in a browser? Some other language accessing the page using WebDriver? Or something else? What version of XPath does your environment support? What else is in the script element? To retrieve just the object you want, you will need to extract it from within the other JSON, and for that we would need to know the structure of that JSON and how the results object you're after fits into that structure.

I guess you're probably running client-side in the browser?
Natively, the browsers only support XPath 1.0, which was defined long before JSON was invented, so you are out of luck there.
There are a couple of third-party libraries that implement a more up-to-date version of XPath: one is my company's product SaxonJS which implements XPath 3.1. With XPath 3.1, given the JSON string shown in your question, you can do:
let $json := ....,
    $entries := parse-json($json)?results
return 
  for $i in 1 to array:size($entries)
  return $entries($i)

But the detail depends on what you want to do with the JSON content...
Alternatively, you might be able to find a suitable library that implements JSONPath, which is a language similar to XPath for accessing JSON rather than XML.
